# serializable object exclude my public property calling from client

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-web-api

I am working in Asp.net web api, my model class is follwoing

```
[Serializable]    
public class Workspace
{
    private string strID;
    public string strName;

    public string ID
    {
        get { return strID; }
        set { strID = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return strName; }
        set { strName = value; }
    }

}
```

I have Following Get Method in controller

```
public Workspace GetWorkSpace()
    {
        if (objWorkspace == null)
        {             
            objWorkspace = new Workspace();
            objWorkspace.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            objWorkspace.Name = "Workspace 1";

        }

        return objWorkspace;
    }
```

I am trying to get this object using Jquery as follows

```
var uri = 'api/workspace/GetWorkspace';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON(uri)
        .done(function (data) {

            $('#workspaceId').append(data.ID);
            $('#workspaceName').append(data.Name);

        });

    });
```

I get the response object in data, but it exclude my public properties **"ID" and "Name"** as shown below

```
strID: "a0a523c6-f657-40df-b957-114b87de02f8"
strName: "Workspace 1"
__proto__: Object
```

As you see response object get  **"strID, and strName"** ,
which are **private variables** in model class, rather it should be **ID and Name** in reponse data,
Moreover, if i remove [Serializable] attribute from my model class, i will get the desired result.
Can any one explain me it, and what i do wrong with [Serializable] attribute

your help will be appreciatable

Comment: you have     **public string strName;** not private.

Comment: Is it your public method in your Controller? I'd suppose you have a method with `ActionResult` return type (even if not strictly required). "Proper" one should be `JsonResult` with `return Json(objWorkspace, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: I don't do much with .NET anymore, but could you try using the `ISerializable` interface and implementing the `GetObjectData` method to choose what will be serialized and how?

Comment: ooops, sory, that actually private variable strName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a custom `ContractResolver`, with setting:

```
public MyResolver()
{
    IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;
}
```

And as documented here [DefaultContractResolver.IgnoreSerializableAttribute Property](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableAttribute.htm):

> true if the SerializableAttribute attribute will be ignored when serializing and deserializing types; otherwise, false.

If you do not plan to implement custom Resolver you can do it like here:

- [ASP.NET Web API and [Serializable] class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263988/)

The snippet cited from that source:

```
((DefaultContractResolver)config
     .Formatters
     .JsonFormatter
     .SerializerSettings
     .ContractResolver
).IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can resolve this problem by decorating the Workspace type with [JsonObject].