# ASP.Net MVC Model binding a [Serializable] class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I have this class

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject {
    // properties omitted
}
```

And this WebAPI controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(string))]
public IHttpActionResult SetMyObject(MyObject o) {
    // process object
}
```

But it fails to model bind to the MyObject class. The object o in the controller method is completely empty, every property is default (so mostly null).

Turns out this is because of the [Serializable] annotation on MyObject. Removing that makes model binding work again.

Is there a way to keep [Serializable] and fix model binding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is in the setting `IgnoreSerializableAttribute` on the *Resolver*

```
((DefaultContractResolver)config.Formatters.JsonFormatter
  .SerializerSettings.ContractResolver)
    .IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true;
```

Check the:

[ASP.NET Web API and [Serializable] class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13263988/1679310)

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the serialization to Json.NET as suggested in the link.

Comment: Great to see that ;) Good luck with Web API