# Web.Api Model Binding for [Serializable] class is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a class like;

```
[Serializable] 
public class ApiClass
{        
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }        
}
```

And in my web api controller method is like;

```
    public Guid Post(ApiClass apiClass)
    {
         // do some stuff with parameter.
    }
```

when I send object as json request, for some reason, if I use  [Serializable] attribute for my class, it does not resolved. But if I remove it I can get values from parameter.

What would be the reason?

Comment: Do you need the [Serializable] attribute for another reason?

Comment: Yes, there is another implementation requires it. I need to pass this object over there.

Comment: Have you tried - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13278092/33116 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/10146330/33116

`IgnoreSerializableAttribute=false` might do the trick

Comment: @WestDiscGolf IgnoreSerializableAttribute=false made the trick. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Model binding should work fine irrespective of the `Serializable` attribute, Make sure your code which sends the data is correct. The below code worked fine with and without `Serializable` attribute on the DTO.

```
$(function() {

    var data = { userId : "Shyju" };

    $.post("api/Values", data, function(response) {
        document.write(response);
    });

});
```

and the server code in Values controller

```
public string Post(ApiClass model)
{
    return "Received" + model.UserId;
}
```

Comment: I am sending identical serialized json body for both cases. And when I add Serializable attribute, it does not fill properties of the parameter. Reverse scenario works though.